# Read a floating point data with F descriptor

Tags: formatting, fortran

I have a data file in the following format:

```
   76     1               28.19345173               20.57121917               21.66248682
   77     1               30.48106325               37.84001977               19.95790222
   78     1               30.49966847                        38               20.68928893
   79     1               1.246861056              0.6998957711               34.74201206
```

I need to do some manipulation on this data file. Thus, I started writing a code to read the 4 last columns of the data file. Here is the format I used to read the wanted information and write it in a new file:

Reading Format :

```
  format(21x,f16.11,10x,f16.11,10x,f16.11)
```

Writing Format:

```
format(A1,1x,f16.11,5x,f16.11,5x,f16.11)
```

Where A1 is automatically set to 1. 
The output of my code is :

```
1   28.19345173000       20.57121917000       21.66248682000
1   30.48106325000       37.84001977000       19.95790222000
1   30.49966847000        0.00000000038       20.68928893000
1    1.24686105600        0.69989577110       34.74201206000
```

As you can easily see my problem is with that 38 in the third row which is read and written as `0.00000000038`. Can anyone kindly help me to figure what the best way is to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion there is no place for using nonzero in the `F` edit descriptor for input. For output it is useful to control the number of decimal places, but it is harmful for input.

As francescalus shows in his answer, the `d` in (`Fw.d`) value causes literals without a decimal symbols to be interpretted as scaled by 10^d.

The solution is to just use `F16.0` and not `F16.11`. Nonzero `d` part is completely unnecessary and harmful. There are just some strange use cases for it, but you don't have them here.

Comment: Dear Vlademir, 
With respect, you did not get the question at all, the zero d is not working to read and write all the elements! 
Sorry but your answer does not address my question at all.

Comment: @H.RJ For output, don't use `F16.0`, but whatever you want.

Comment: My respected friends,
I fully understand it. I think you have not got my main concern :-)!
I am just trying to learn fortran, i want to know if fortran is able to switch from f16.11 to f16.0 whenever the user needs or not.
Sorry for any inconveniences but i am not after to find a solution in the simplest way but trying to learn!

Comment: @H.RJ Believe me, I got your question. Just don't use anything at all than `.0` in the `F` descriptor for **input**, period. There is **no** reason to use it (in your case). Did you at least tried my suggestion. I know it works because I DID try it. Keep what you already have for output.

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected behaviour comes from the fact that the input field `38` has no decimal symbol.  You can see this is different from all of the others.

Why is this an issue?  Let's look at how the `F` edit descriptor, with `Fw.d`, is described for input (Fortran 2008, 10.7.2.3.2):

> If the decimal symbol is omitted, the rightmost d digits of the string, with leading zeros assumed if necessary, are interpreted as the fractional part of the value represented.

For your edit `F16.11` the fractional part consists of 11 digits.  That leads to `3.8e-10`.

A simple way to handle this is to ensure that all your floating point fields contain a decimal symbol.

---

As [Vladimir F points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984324) the simplest way is actually to modify the edit to use `F16.0`.  This follows from the sentence before the one I quoted:

> The d has no effect on input if the input field contains a decimal symbol.

So, using `0` as the fractional width in input has the desired result: when there is a decimal symbol the value `0` here is ignore; when there isn't, that's the same as having on fraction part.  For output you can still use the format as you have it.  It's just the input going wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am dealing with millions of elements. There is no way to ensure if all of the elements contain of a decimal symbol or not. Assume all elements have decimal symbols except this one, what you kindly answered basically means that there is no way to report a number without decimal symbol. Right?

Comment: In other words, what is the best way to read elements that some of them contain decimal symbol and some do not?

Comment: If you don't want to change the datafile (which is reasonable) then you could also look into using list-directed input (`read(...,fmt=*)`) rather than have the explicit format.  That's a compromise (see other questions), but could be an easy way if you trust the file is otherwise well-presented.  Beyond that, more effort in parsing the input line could be made (other questions on that are also available).

Comment: Well, using fmt=* does not work out at all. The reason is very so clear. I need to read and write the last three columns of my input file while * reads the entire line!

Comment: That's the point of the "discarded" values.  You read the entire line, but just select those you want for further processing.  I note the question actually says 4 columns, but I guess that's a typo?

Comment: Well How can I discard the first two columns and use the last three columns for further processing?

Comment: You read them in (here to `j` and `k`) but you just don't reference them again.

Comment: you should post that as an answer since it really is the best approach.

Comment: @agentp Sorry, which part?  If you mean my "list-directed" part, then that was in a [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31983393/5) of the answer.  I thought, on reflection, though that it does more harm than good - especially in light of the other answer.  List-directed has so many drawbacks for an otherwise well-structured file that it only makes sense when you forget about 0 fractional width.

Comment: I don't see the harm in using list directed input.  The only issue I can see would arise if one of the fields was blank.

Comment: @agentp You have a point.  I'll see if I can come up with a version that makes us both happy.